# How do I overlay a video/image over my screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I'm looking for a way to overlay an image or a video on top of a screen without a GUI. If you've ever opened FL Studio, that's what I'm going for. I'm trying to do this in Python.

I've looked around and can only find overlaying images on top of a GUI, nothing on the base screen.

[Here's what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/576ca.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind! I figured it out:

```
win.config(bg = "#f0f0f0")
win.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','#f0f0f0')
win.wm_attributes('-fullscreen',True)
win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: None)
```